# Probability question about removal and addition of original group.

Tags: probability

I am not sure how to phrase my question in such a manner that I can search for info online. Here is an example of a problem:

I have 3 cards. Two are black and the other is red. I remove one random card. The remaining two have 2/3 chance of containing the red card. Now I add a black card and then choose a random card from the new group. What is this chosen card's chance of being red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the red card to be chosen, we have to remove a black card, with probability $\frac23$, and then chose the red card, with probability $\frac13$, so the probability is $\frac23\cdot\frac13=\frac29$.